# Smart search is not working when working with mergeMap

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to use smart search in angular

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="leadForm" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of results" [value]="item">
   {{item}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

leadForm = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
```

Then in `ngOnInit()`

```
 combineLatest([s1,s2,s3])
 .pipe(
 mergeMap(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
     this.x = r1;
     this.y = r2;
     this.names = r3;
     return of(1);
 }))
 .subscribe(() => {
     // display
 });
 this.leadForm.valuesChanges.subscribe(
     r => {
       if(r !== '') {
           this.results = this.names.filter(c => c.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase()));
       }
    }
 );
```

So the idea is to get the names from data stream then populate the dropdown. However sometimes it is not working. I guess that the stream order is wrong. We need to get this.names first. How to change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a more reactive approach where you declare variables for your Observables and react to changes in those variables.

Without the exact code, it's hard to get an exact example for you, but something like this:

```
names$ = this.http.get(...);

leadForm$ = this.leadForm.valueChanges();

results$ = combineLatest([names$, leadForm$]).pipe(
     map(([names, r]) => names.filter(c => c.toLowerCase().includes(r.toLowerCase()))
);
```

This should get you close.

You can then subscribe to `results$` somewhere or bind directly to it using an async pipe.

I have an example of this technique here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EefbG6N3vY

And if you have a Pluralsight subscription, there is a complete walk through here: https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=5732473c-ac12-450d-930c-096a687dd2d0

Comment: I like your idea to put related into combineLatest. But except `names$, leadForm$`, I have others such as r1, r2 in the example, should I use another combineLatest?

Comment: It really depends on what you are using them for. If you need them as part of your filter, then they could be added to the shown combineLatest. The specifics of what you need depends entirely on how they will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to know what s1 -- s3 is..

But in general you should refactor this so that results is an observable dependent on leadForm.valueChanges.

Something like:

```js
this.results$ = this.leadForm.valueChanges.pipe(map(...));
```

Your problem here is that you subscribe 2 observables and expect that the order is defined, but there can be these cases for BOTH: it never resolves, one of them resolves first(last respectively), there is an error. To give you more advice I would need to know more about the case.. :/

Comment: s1, s2 and s3 are http get request. For example `s1= return this.http.get<IMyDto>(this.url);`

Comment: and what do they do? because if you need them for results than you should make it like 

this.results$ = combinelatest(s1,s2,s3, this.leadForm.valueChanges).pipe(map(..))

this would be really async.

And also subscribe in the template with |" async as results" syntax

Comment: Could please double check my question? I got this.names first then I use this.leadForm.valueChanges to get the second result for dropdown. Your code seems reverse the order. And I would like the entire code. Thanks